# Can I use notepad++ to edit my.cnf

Tags: mysql, notepad++

Can I use notepad++ to edit my.cnf  , to tell the truth I don't much about mysql, but it seems that I have to optimize mysql, so thats all the reason. I am wary about pico, nano, as I don't know how to use them and the command lines.

Comment: A text editor is a text editor. `my.cnf` is a text file. So yes, you can use any text editor to edit a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. This is the header of that file:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
```